# Angular $http post to MVC action, parameter is null

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

So I do this post:

```
$http.post(Common.blog.save, { blog: blog })
    .then(saveBlogComplete)
    .catch(function(message) {

    });
```

And I get this in fiddler output:

```
{"blog":{"title":"Chicken Is Good","content":"#Chicken Is Good\n##Contents\n* Introduction\n* Factfile\n* Analysis\n* Evaluation\n* Conclusion\n###Introduction\n\n###Factfile","dateAuthored":"","userId":""}}
```

In my action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(string blog)
{
    var desBlog = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlogDto>(blog);

    return this.ExecuteService(() => this.blogService.Save(desBlog));
}
```

`string blog` is coming back null.... I'm not sure why this is happening?

**I have done the following**

- Put breakpoint in JavaScript - data is getting populated
- Reviewed Fiddler output - the data is the same as JavaScript obj
- Put breakpoint in the Action - it's getting called, the HttpContext doesn't have any data about the POST data in it

Comment: Did you try stringifying the object? `{blog: JSON.stringify(blog)}` (uses the JSON2 js library)

Comment: i didn't, I will give it a go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to `stringify` the data!

```
$http.post(Common.blog.save, { blog: JSON.stringify(blog) })
    .then(saveBlogComplete)
    .catch(function(message) {

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work without `stringify` function, if you change your mvc action parameter from `String` to `Blog`:

```
public class Blog
{
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public string Content {get; set;}
   public DateTime DateAuthored {get; set;}
   public long UserId {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(Blog blog)
{
```

This happening because your `blog` model on server-side doesn't match to the structure of passing parameter from angular.

Comment: That will automatically create the blog object from the posted data, but I believe MVC still expects the data to be posted in string format.